# Powershell script unable to find type System.Security.Cryptography.RijndaelManagedTransform

Tags: powershell, encryption, .net-framework-version

I have a Powershell script in which I use the module `System.Security.Cryptography.RijndaelManagedTransform`. I used to execute my script with Powershell 5.1 and everything worked fine. I need some features from Powershell 7 and therefore am executing the script now with Powershell 7. However in my script I get an error now.

The error points to the following line in New-StringDecryption:

```
[System.Security.Cryptography.RijndaelManagedTransform]$objectDecryptor = $encryptionObject.CreateDecryptor()
```

The error states:

> Unable to find type [System.Security.Cryptography.RijndaelManagedTransform]

This seems to me that Powershell cannot find the module. However, why did it work when running the script with Powershell 5.1?

I already tried adding these lines to the script, but it did not help:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Security
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Core
```

Comment: Some of the crypto APIs have been slightly re-designed during the port to .NET Core, and the `RijndaelManagedTransform` type no longer exists. `RijndaelManaged.CreateDecryptor()` still returns an `ICryptoTransform`, have you tried simply removing the cast? If that doesn't help, please post a complete code sample along with any other errors you might run into

Comment: Thanks, removing the type cast did the trick!